# show the value of an attribute of a product magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

i need show value the hardness attribute is type text

The code:

> ```
> <?php
>
> require_once("app/Mage.php");
>
> Mage::app();
>
> $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
>
> foreach($products as $product)  
> {
>
>     $sku = $product->getSku();
>     if($sku == '5555')
>     {
>         echo '<pre>';
>
>         $x = $product->getResource();
>         $y = $x->getAttribute('name');
>         $z = $y->getSource();
>         $attr = $z->getAttribute('name');
>         echo get_class($attr);
>         echo "Nombre: ".$attr->getName()." ID: ".$attr->getId();
>         echo "<br />-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />";
>         echo '</pre>';
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: can not understand your question>plz explaing

Comment: Do you want hardness product attribute value or do you want all details of an attribute hardness?

Comment: I need the attribute value

Answer (score 0):

```
$products =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('hardness');

foreach($products as $product)  
{
  echo $product->getHardness();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to `load product` to get product attribute.

```
<?php

    require_once("app/Mage.php");

    Mage::app();

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    foreach($products as $product)  
    {
    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

        $sku = $product->getSku();
        if($sku == '5555')
        {
            echo '<pre>';

            $x = $product->getResource();
            $y = $x->getAttribute('name');
            $z = $y->getSource();
            $attr = $z->getAttribute('name');
            echo get_class($attr);
            echo "Nombre: ".$attr->getName()." ID: ".$attr->getId();
            echo "<br />-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />";
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
```